# Override val with different type - Chisel

Tags: scala, variable-assignment, chisel

I would like to use the variable `cache` to be connected to another class named `NewCache` which uses an extended IO bundle of the one used for `Cache` class. But I get the following error:

```
[error]overriding lazy value cache in class Processor of type Mem.Cache;  
[error]lazy value cache has incompatible type.  
[error]override lazy val cache = Module(new NewCache(conf))
```

I assume I get this error because it can only override value cache in class NewProcessor as type Cache. So I wonder if there is any possible way to completely reassign `cache` value when I use the class `NewProcessor`.

```
class Processor(inputid: Int){
    val conf = new Conf(inputid)
    lazy val cache = Module(new Cache(conf))

    cache.io.cache_req <> io.cache.req
}

class NewProcessor(inputid: Int) extends Processor(inputid){
    override lazy val cache = Module(new NewCache(conf))

    cache.io.tag_cache_req <> io.tag_cache.req
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making `NewCache` extend `Cache`?

Comment: @jkoenig Yes, I have. The thing is that most of the code for `NewProcessor` is quite different from `Processor`. Yet many of the variable names in these two classes are matching, thus conflicting each other. Therefore in my opinion the ideal solution would be to not extend `Cache`, if there is another way around. Otherwise I guess the only option would be to use `lazy` variables in `Processor` and then override those variables in `NewProcessor`?

Comment: Right, so if `NewProcessor` is quite different from `Processor` then it seems you should consider not using inheritance there either. Inheritance only really makes sense for things that are very similar and can be used in similar contexts. While this more of a general software engineering problem, for Chisel designs I find that direct Module inheritance is generally not the right way to do it. Composition works well for most cases (esp. where implementations differ significantly). Inheritance works well for things like Modules that have a common interface.

Comment: @jkoenig yes, it sounds like composition is the right solution here. Any guide on how to do this in Chisel design?

Comment: The principle is the same as in any programming language. You want to factor common code into [functions](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/blob/master/src/main/scala/chisel3/util/LFSR.scala#L20) or [classes](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/blob/master/src/main/scala/chisel3/util/Counter.scala#L15). Classes are nice if you want a custom data type with methods that will do hardware generation. [Chisel Modules](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/blob/master/src/main/scala/chisel3/util/Arbiter.scala#L35) are also useful if you want them to map to Verilog modules which is useful for debugging.